# Java continuous loop until input of special character

Tags: java, while-loop

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int r = 0;
        int h = 0;
        System.out.print("Write your two numbers (numerator, denominator): ");
        Scanner userpress = new Scanner(System.in);
        userpress.useDelimiter("\\s");

        while (userpress.hasNextInt()) {
            r = userpress.nextInt();
            if (userpress.hasNextInt()) {
                h = userpress.nextInt();
                int x = r / h;
                System.out.print(x + " ");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        String s = userpress.next();
        if ("e".equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
            message();
        }
    }

    private static void message() {
        System.out.println("user pressed e");
    }
}
```

I want the while loop to run continuously until the input is `e`. The inputs should be numbers only. If it's something else other than ints, then I want it to be ignored and have the while loop run again until the user inputs `e`.

For example, I want to be able to write `10 5` (enter), then get output `2`; then I will input again `20 5`, and I will get output 4. If I write `20 4 g`, then I want the `g` to be ignored, but I don't want the program to be terminated. I want the while loop to run continuously until user inputs `e`. If I write `20 4 e`, then I want to get `5` and then `message()`.

Is it possible to check everything as int, or do I have to check everything as string and parseInt it?

I kind of solved it by adding an infinite for-loop surrounding the while loop, and the `if ("e".equalsIgnoreCase(s))`. Is there no better way?

Comment: I would use a `do-while` block with the exit condition in it.

Comment: can you please show me in code how you mean

Comment: It seems you are looking to operate on lines of text. You might consider using a `java.io.BufferedReader` and use the `[readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--)` method.  Then you can pass one line at a time to a processing method.

Comment: As a user - I want...

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.print("Write your two numbers (numerator, denominator): " );
        Scanner userpress = new Scanner( System.in );
        userpress.useDelimiter("\\s");

        Integer numerator = null;
        while ( userpress.hasNextInt() || !"e".equalsIgnoreCase( userpress.next() ) ) {
            if ( userpress.hasNextInt() ) {
                if ( numerator == null ) {
                    numerator = userpress.nextInt();
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println( numerator.intValue() / userpress.nextInt() );
                    numerator = null;
                }
            }
        }
        message();
    }


    private static void message() {
        System.out.println("user pressed e");
    }
```

This solution doesn't check divisions by zero.

Comment: didnt solve my issue. doesnt repons when i input e

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake in my code. it worked! I wonder if there are simplier ways.

Comment: OK, I think this is the simplest solution I can think of. Cheers